# Widevine DRM support in samsung smart tv

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

In my app i want to implement widevine drm. I got to know from some website that samsung smart tv supports widewine drm. But i didn't got how to use the drm in my smart tv app. Can anyone help me in how to use the widevine drm in samsung smart tv app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guide [How_to_use_Widevine_solution_in_Samsung_App_v1.6.pdf](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Common/FileDownLoad?BoardType=6b8cf359de61b749&fileID=50c249a24b7ea8cb) is attached to [forum message](http://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/fc9db838bc1a1dd3?forumID=1320cd7b5ebca0fc).

[This forum message](http://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/a56519250d733296?forumID=e5b9426a2d1f41c9) contains example of widevine playback url.

If you have contract with Widevine, they supply documentation and integration samples.

Comment: I read the document. I dont know how to get the stream Id. Do you know  how to get that @IvanSolntsev

Comment: If you don`t know actual value, try use `1`. Or don`t specify it at all. In basic case your WVM container have only one stream.

Comment: hey hii my DRM_URL needs to send some parameter and its a post request then how I will send those parameter through url

Comment: I don't think it is possible with Samsung. In fact, I never seen any player on any platform, that use POST instead of GET to request playlists. If you need to pass GET parameter, than just specify them after `?` and before `|`.